# Is it possible to add a Relative Time Field to a Kibana Datatable

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, kibana-6

I would like to add a field to a datatable which shows the elapsed time based on another date field.  Specifically, I have a field which provides the event date and time, and need another field which shows that event happened 1 day 2 hours and 15 minutes ago.  When they look at the same visualization a minute later the field should update to 1 day 2 hours and 16 minutes ago.

I know that I can have users select the time range they would like to focus on, but I'm attempting to duplicate functionality from a previous (non-ELK) solution which offered this field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here's what I came up with:

```
long different = (System.currentTimeMillis() - doc['BeginDate'].value);
long secondsInMilli = 1000;
long minutesInMilli = secondsInMilli * 60;
long hoursInMilli = minutesInMilli * 60;
long daysInMilli = hoursInMilli * 24;

long elapsedDays = different / daysInMilli;
different = different % daysInMilli;

long elapsedHours = different / hoursInMilli;
different = different % hoursInMilli;

long elapsedMinutes = different / minutesInMilli;
different = different % minutesInMilli;

long elapsedSeconds = different / secondsInMilli;
different = different % secondsInMilli;

if(elapsedSeconds < 1) {
   different.toString() + " milliseconds";
} else if (elapsedSeconds == 1) {
    elapsedSeconds.toString() + " second, " + different.toString() + " milliseconds";
} else if (elapsedMinutes < 1) {
    elapsedSeconds.toString() + " seconds, " + different.toString() + " milliseconds";
} else if (elapsedMinutes == 1) {
    elapsedMinutes.toString() + " minute, " + elapsedSeconds.toString() + " seconds";
} else if (elapsedHours < 1) {
    elapsedMinutes.toString() + " minutes, " + elapsedSeconds.toString() + " seconds";
} else if (elapsedHours == 1) {
    elapsedHours.toString() + " hour, " + elapsedMinutes.toString() + " minutes";
} else if (elapsedDays < 1) {
    elapsedHours.toString() + " hours, " + elapsedMinutes.toString() + " minutes";
} else if (elapsedDays == 1) {
    elapsedDays.toString() + " day, " + elapsedHours.toString() + " hours";
} else {
  elapsedDays.toString() + " days, " + elapsedHours.toString() + " hours"; 
}
```

I added a scripted field to the Index Pattern, chose "painless" for language, "date" for Type, "String" for Format, and Transform is "- none -".

It isn't pretty, but it appears to work.  I'm certain that it could be improved greatly, but it appears to fit my needs.  Hope this helps someone else.